# AlarmManager and PendingIntents no long work reliably on newer versions of Android, what to do?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarms

I have an app that I created that has worked well for years, but now is giving me problems on the latest versions of Android. Until now, it had worked on various Samsung Galaxy devices (S3, S4, S5, Note 4), however it seems that running it on Android 6.0.1 or later seems to have broken functionality.

I was tired of Google's Push Notifications and relying on it for my app, so I had decided to create my own custom push notifications using my server.

I used AlarmManager and a combination of Intents, Listeners, and Wake Lock to run every 15 seconds to check messages on my server. It had worked well, however now the Intent Service no longer receives the intents. After digging into it, I figured out that AlarmManager was no longer sending out the intents reliably every 15 seconds. At best, once the device becomes inactive, AlarmManager might trigger the intent every 3-5 minutes. On the Galaxy S8, it can take hours.

I figured that there was some power setting built into Android in newer versions that was killing my app and stopping it from running in the background. I've tried making sure the app was not restricted by turning off the "Optimize Battery Usage" Android feature setting for the app, however that does not seem to have made any difference. Task Killers are also not the culprit in this case.

What should I do? The code for AlarmManager and sending the intent is:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent("com.my.app.PushNotifications");
PendingIntent pushintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 555555, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 15000, pushintent);
```

Comment: Try using a job scheduling api. I would recommend you take a look at the `firebase-jobdispatcher`. This handles issues raised in your question. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

Comment: "I used AlarmManager and a combination of Intents, Listeners, and Wake Lock to run every 15 seconds to check messages on my server" -- this is why users hate Android's battery life. It's why Android 5.1 limited alarms to once a minute, why Android 6.0 added Doze mode to dramatically curtail such app behavior, and why device manufacturers have added yet more restrictions on top of that. Also, your code will fail outright on Android 8.0+, because you are using implicit broadcasts, which are no longer supported.

Comment: @codeFreak Thanks, that was a helpful link that seems ideal for a replacement for AlarmManager. I am a little hesitant to use outside libraries that may expire given time though. Regardless, I will try Firebase and see how it goes. Would you have any suggestions for something Android has inbuilt? I was thinking of rewriting a service, but I have a feeling that will end up being killed as well. Thanks for your help, I truly appreciate it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Not helpful. Custom needs often require custom design.

Comment: "Custom needs often require custom design" -- keeping the radios in full-power mode 24x7, and the CPU powered on most of the time, is the sort of design that causes users to hate Android's battery life. This is why Google has been waging the War on Background Processing since the release of Android 4.4, raising the stakes significantly with the introduction of [Doze mode in Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html).

Comment: Beyond that, if your app can live with polling a few times an hour at best, `JobScheduler` or `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` on `AlarmManager` can help. Your original solution of using push messaging (GCM/FCM) is what Google wants you to use, and if you need quasi-real-time updates, that's your only simple option.